# Changing the font size in the epub_view package

Tags: flutter

I use epub_view package to display epub files
I want to change the font size of the content
How can this be done and is there an alternative package in which this can be done?

my current code:

```
EpubController _epubController = EpubController(
    document: EpubDocument.openAsset('assets/book.epub'),
  );

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text('Show File'),
      ),
      body: EpubView(
        controller: _epubController,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried Global font size multiplier? Not sure if it works, but give it a try. https://stasheq.medium.com/flutter-global-font-size-multiplier-b1826cbc889